# php xml PDO insert query error

Tags: php, forms, pdo

hey i'm attempting to pass xml values using this hidden form:

```
<form method='post' action='addholiday.php'  id='addHoliday'>
<input type='hidden' name='title' id='title' value= '.$holiday->title'>
<input type='hidden' name='link' id='link' value= '.$holiday->link'>
<input type='hidden' name='date' id='date' value= '.$holiday->pudDate'>
<input type='hidden' name='description' id='description' value= '.$holiday->description'>
    <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Add Holiday'>";
```

and insert the values in to mysql database using the PDO process:

```
 $db = getConnection();

//get holiday infor from hidden form
$user = $_SESSION['user'];
$title = $_POST['title'];
$link = $_POST['link'];
$date = $_POST['date'];
$description = $_POST['description'];

//insert the values in to favorties table
 $sql = "INSERT INTO saved_holidays (subscriberID, link, pubDate, title, description,dateSaved) 
VALUES (:subscriberID, :link, :pubDate, :title, :description, now())";

$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt ->bindParam(':subscriberID', $user);
$stmt ->bindParam(':link', $link);
$stmt ->bindParam(':pubDate',$date);
$stmt ->bindParam(':title', $title);
$stmt ->bindParam(':description', $description);

$stmt->execute(array($user, $link, $date, $title, $description ));
```

however i keep getting this error message when i attempt to use the form

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: 
Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined' in     var/www/vhosts/numyspace.co.uk/web_users/home/~unn_w11023553/public_html/holiday/addholiday    .php:39 Stack trace: #0
/var/www/vhosts/numyspace.co.uk/web_users/home/~unn_w11023553/public_html/holiday/addholiday.php(39):PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/vhosts/numyspace.co
.uk/web_users/home/~unn_w11023553/public_html/holiday/addholiday.php on line 39
```

I'm relatively new to using PDO so any help would be appreciated thanks

Comment: Try removing the space between `$stmt` and `->bindParam`.

Comment: I didn't try PDO much yet, but aren't you supposed to bindParam() **or** pass the values with the array in execute() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `execute` if you're going to use `bindParam` in such a way (and vice versa).  You do need to pass the array as key => value with the keys as the symbols used in the query ("symbol" being borrowed from Ruby terminology).

Answer (score 0):

You're passing the parameters in both the `execute` method and binding them to the statment with `bindParam` - you only need to do one or the other!